# How to show an image from a database using PHP and twig

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, twig

I am trying to show an image from a database using `PHP`and `twig`. I am having a big trouble to achieve this. In my `index.twig` I have this line of code: `<a><img class="images" src="showImg.php?id={{ text.getImage() }}" /></a>`.
The `{{ text.getImage() }}` is coming from a `for-loop` and `showImg.php` will do the query of selecting the image based on the given `ID` parameter.
In my `showImg.php`:

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = intval($_GET['id']);
    $sql = "SELECT filename, mime, code FROM Img_col WHERE id = :id";
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    while($row = $stmt->fetchObject('Image')) {
        $this->result[] = $row;
    }
    Header("Content-type: $img->getMime()");
    Header("Content-Disposition: filename=\"$img->getFileName()\"");
    $img->hentCode();
}
```

My first problem is the IDE stops in the line `$stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);` and my second problem is how to send the image(`code`) to `index.twig`. 
Any idea or hint to help me is very appreciate it. I am open to any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you want to achieve, but this can be done very quickly in Symfony. You need a controller which will create your response according to the route:

```
/**
 * @Route("/image/{id}", name="image")
 */
public function imageAction($id)
{
    $image =  $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Image')->findOneBy(array('id'=> $id));  
    return $this->render('image.html.twig', array('image' => $image));
}
```

Obviously you will need a simple Image class in your AppBundle with at least two fields: id and imageName.

And in your image.html.twig:

```
<img src="/images/{{ image.imageName }}"/>
```

Check out the documentation for more information: 
[Symfony Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/index.html)